# Check if EditText Empty in android Edittext and Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

i'm trying to check if this edittext is empty, then show the `Toast`

here is my fragment:

```
public class First extends Fragment {
    Context mContext;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro1, container, false);
        return v;

        EditText txtun= (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.usredt);
        if ("".equals(txtun.getText().toString().trim())) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "You did not enter a value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return;
        }
    }

}
```

and Here is my **sliderLayout**:

```
public class SilderLayouts extends AppIntro2 {
    @Override
    public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        addSlide(new First(), getApplicationContext());
        addSlide(new Second(), getApplicationContext());
        addSlide(new Third(), getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void loadMainActivity(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.client.test.StartActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDonePressed() {
        loadMainActivity();
    }


}
```

**i tried somethings like:**

`Context` adding in above the `@Override`
`First.this,` in `Toast`

But it didnt work.

Remember, there is a problem in `Return` and if this return deleted, problem exist in Toast.

How to acheive this?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you get the value from the EditText? How does the user input it. As I'm seeing it the view is created and you want to get a value from the EditText which will never have a value at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 EditText txtun= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.usredt);
    if (txtun.getText().toString().compareToIgnoreCase("") == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "You did not enter a value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to solve your problem

```
class First extends FragmentActivity {
        Context mContext;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.intro1, null);


            EditText txtun= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.usredt);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtun.getText().toString().trim())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You did not enter a value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return v;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which is your base activity ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in using the context. Try something like this:

```
public class First extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro1, container, false);
        EditText txtun= (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.usredt);
        if ("".equals(txtun.getText().toString().trim())) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You did not enter a value!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return v;
    }

}
```